# Recalculating normal with curve (sine wave)

Tags: c++, opengl, hlsl, normals

I'm trying to make a water geometry shader that waves using a sine wave.

For each vertex I calculate a sine for x and y, and then offset the vertex to the result * normal.

Because I offset my vertex I have to recalculate my normals, but if I do this using their triangle I get hard edges, while it should be smooth waves.

I understand that somehow I should use that sine function and get a 3D normal from it, but I'm puzzled.

Could someone explain how you get the normal of a sin calculation in 3D space?

Answer (score 3):

You don't give the exact function you use, but it sounds like it's something like:

```
z = a * sin(b * x) * sin(b * y)
```

I'll walk through the process, so you should be able to apply the recipe even if your function looks slightly differently. Also, if your wave is not relative to the xy-plane, you can still use the same calculation, and then apply the necessary transformation matrix to the resulting normal.

What we have here is a parametric surface, where the 3 coordinates of a point of the plane are calculated from two parameters. In this case, the parameters are `x` and `y`, and the vector describing each point is:

```
          [ x                           ]
v(x, y) = [ y                           ]
          [ a * sin(b * x) * sin(b * y) ]
```

The process described here works for any parametric surface, including common geometric shapes. For example for a torus, the two parameters would be two angles. The mathematical tools needed for calculating are basic analysis (derivatives) and some vector geometry (cross product).

As the first step, we calculate the gradient vector for each of the two parameters. These gradient vectors consist of the partial derivatives of each vector component with the corresponding parameter. In the example, the results are:

```
              [ 1                               ]
dv(x, y)/dx = [ 0                               ]
              [ a * b * cos(b * x) * sin(b * y) ]


              [ 0                               ]
dv(x, y)/dy = [ 1                               ]
              [ a * b * sin(b * x) * cos(b * y) ]
```

The normal vector is calculated as the cross product of these two gradient vectors:

```
     [ - a * b * cos(b * x) * sin(b * y) ]
vn = [ - a * b * sin(b * x) * cos(b * y) ]
     [ 1                                 ]
```

Then you normalize this vector, and `vn / |vn|` is your normal vector.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply, I understand what should happen and gave it a try but I can't come up with a correct result. My version of the wave function looks like this: AmpX * sin(SpeedX * Time * ScaleX * pos.x); I use this formula to calculate a float 'Animation' and add the same formula to it but with Z. Then I use this offset to move my vertex by this amount times his normal. Then I need to recalculate the normal and my derived function tools like this: AmpX * (sin(SpeedX * Time + ScaleX * pos.x) + ScaleX * pos.x * cos(SpeedX * time + ScaleX * pos.x)) Then I take the cross of them.

Comment: I got my derived function from http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+x+a+*+sin%28b+*+c+%2B+d+*+x%29 and the result looks somewhat correct (as the normal seem to move) but I also need to recalculate the tangent, I do this by taking the normalized cross of the normal and one of the derived vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the derivative in x and y so you can construct 2 vectors `1,0,x'` and `0,1,y'` then you take the cross product and normalize. That will be the normal.

Comment: do you mean: normalize(cross(float3(1, 0, dx), float3(0, 1, dy))) cause that doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @user1091566 I assumed that the original plane was horizontal (with Z being up)